# Grammatical person and the generic you

Tags: list-of-languages, pronouns, person

In English, the second-person pronoun *you* can be used indefinitely. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you) labels the generic *you* as an indefinite personal pronoun. Nonetheless, unlike pronouns such as *one* and *anyone*, the generic *you* is never used with a third-person singular verb form. Consequently, the generic *you* is arguably not an indefinite pronoun. If the generic *you* is not an indefinte pronoun, then it is preferable to view the generic *you* as a second-person pronoun used rhetorically.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you), the generic *you* appears in numerous languages. Is it possible for a language to have a generic pronoun that is related to the second-person pronoun and that does not take the second-person verb form?

Comment: “Consequently”? The implication that indefinite pronouns must be used specifically with verbs in the third person _singular_, specifically, is demonstrably incorrect, given that English itself has plural indefinite pronouns (_others_, _some_, _several_, _few_, _many_, etc.) – but even without the singular restriction, who says indefinite pronouns must necessarily take third-person agreement? Even if you don’t consider generic _you_ to actually be an indefinite pronoun, it would be perfectly reasonable for a language to have pronouns meaning ‘some of us’ or ‘some of you’.

Comment: Is it possible to view generic you as an indefinite pronoun that takes second-person agreement?

Comment: I don’t see why not. If _one_ (and similar pronouns in other languages, like French _(l’)on_, German _man_, etc.) can be considered an indefinite pronoun, surely so can generic _you_ when the meaning is precisely the same. The terms ‘definite’ and ‘indefinite’ are based on the **meaning** of the pronoun, after all.

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical categories of person and number (which cause verb agreement) don't always correspond with the semantics of what they refer to. This is why "they" takes plural agreement, even when it's referring to a single person ("if you see **a child** who **is** struggling, see if **they are** all right"); similarly for "you" ("**you are** my only **friend**").

Similarly, indefinite "you" takes second person plural verb agreement (grammatically), even when it doesn't refer to the specific person or people being addressed (semantically).